# Django admin Cannot Submit Form

Tags: javascript, django, web, iframe, django-admin

I face some trouble while accessing **django admin**. It turns out that cannot create new objects from Django Admin.

Here is how it looks if I want to create new user:
[image]

I got the error

```
Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.
```

Is there something that I should add in my **settings** file to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you click a link from an application, the tab opened will have javascript disabled/sandboxed.

Close the tab and reopen the same URL in a fresh tab, it might work.